# Can static member function without any argument access private attributes of a class?

Tags: c++, arduino

I have following (simplified) ServerHandler.h file

```
#include <WebServer.h>

class ServerHandler
{
    public:
    ServerHandler();
    void createServer();
    static void handlePage();

    private:
    WebServer server;
};
```

And ServerHandler.cpp file

```
#include "ServerHandler.h"

ServerHandler::ServerHandler() : server(80)
{}

void ServerHandler::createServer()
{
    // this code does not work
    server.on("/page", handlePage); 
    
    // lambda functions are proper to use
    server.on("/hey", [this]() {
        server.send(200, "text/plain", "Hello");
    });

    server.begin();
}

void ServerHandler::handlePage ()
{
    server.send(200, "text/plain", "This is a page");   
}
```

In WebServer.h server.on() is defined as:

```
typedef std::function<void(void)> THandlerFunction;
void on(const Uri &uri, THandlerFunction handler);
```

All I want is to write a free function/static method/member method etc for long server operations called as handlePage().

Problem is I cannot use a static function with argument like `pageHandler(Server s&)` because I cannot use this function in `server.on("/page", pageHandler(s));`

Additionally, I do not want to use lambda function as in the code becase my goal is to seperate long operations.

Briefly, how to deal with `server.on("/page", ?);` ?

Comment: `server` is an instance member, so the `static` function needs to know which instance it belongs to in order to refer to the correct one

Comment: @UnholySheep yes you are correct, but can you make it possible without using an argument.

Comment: No, without an argument you'd need a `static` variable that you could refer to in the function, which would bring a lot of other problems

Comment: @UnholySheep Do you think that thing like singleton is useful?

Comment: A singleton is a design pattern with a very specific goal in mind. If it fits your needs then it may be a good solution, but that is something only you can answer

Comment: @UnholySheep I said on top of your comment. Maybe server can be static member of a function and static methods can reach it via createOrGetServerInstance() function. Not sure this will going to work but it seems worth to try. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to declare it as `static` to begin with? why don't just declare it a `private` method as `void handlepage()`? It is a callback function of `server.on()` route and only used by the route anyway. In fact, you don't even need the `ServerHandler` class, all you need is to group all the related functions in a separate file called it `serverhanddlers.h` and `#include `server handlers.h` in your main sketch. C++ is not Java, not everything need to be in a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I learn it is possible to use member functions thank to @hcheung, I researched how to do it and found.

Requirement:

```
typedef std::function<void(void)> THandlerFunction;
void on(const Uri &uri, THandlerFunction handler);
```

To use **non-static member function** I need to use binding.

```
mServer.on("/control_servo", std::bind(&ServerHandler::handlePage, this));
```

Comment: This is equivalent to the lambda solution `mServer.on("/control_servo", [this] { handlePage(); });`. Either way, the `ServerHandler` object must still exist when the callback is invoked.